# H3 contained by div cannot be vertically centered

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my h3 not vertically centering. In firebug, if I change the top:50% to top:51% and back again, it fixes itself.

The H3 in the div needs to be vertically centered.

link: [here](http://www.onlineagentuk.co.uk/reviews-demo)

css:

```
.review-large {
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:127px;
    background-image: url(../images/review-images/quote-left.jpg), url(../images/review-images/quote-right.jpg);
    background-position: left center, right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
}

.review-large h3 {
    color: #00adee;
    font-size: 33px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 33px;
    padding:0 60px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should used the table/table-cell behavior. Put the container at display:table; and h3 at table-cell; and set the vertical align: middle. Also remove the position transform and top like:

```
.review-large {
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:127px;
    background-image: url(../images/review-images/quote-left.jpg), url(../images/review-images/quote-right.jpg);
    background-position: left center, right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
}

.review-large h3 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #00adee;
    font-size: 33px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 33px;
    padding:0 60px;
    position: relative;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this method, and the padding required on the left and right doesn't work with tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
.review-large{
display: table;
height: 127px;
}
.review-large h3{
display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Add display table property and change min-height to height, dont worry about fixed height, table property is flexiable by itself.

and remove transform and top and other unused property from h3.

Answer (score 0):

h3 {
    color: #00adee;

> **display: block;**

```
font-size: 33px;
font-weight: bold;
```

> **line-height: 127px;**

```
padding: 0 60px;
vertical-align: middle;
```

}